# TKINTER: Howto auto-update loop generated labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm battling with tkinter's .after() functionality, and I see all the examples, these all work as demo in my environment **if applied on a well-known amount of labels**

The challenge I have here is that I have **an unknown amount of labels generated by a loop**.

I need to have these labels regenerated and overwritten every x seconds. The number of labels may change, text and color of the labels will change accordingly, as well.

I think **the challenge here** is to re-run the whole labels generation function **_construct_label_colorise** after x seconds, and have it replace previous labels.

Think of it as like these labels would be a list of windows processes, each time it constructs labels - some processes might go down and disappear, and some appear on top. so, every second the number of labels will be different. For this example, I limit the delta to 3-5.labels.

**Please advise** a way to correctly implement _construct_label_colorise function rerun, after x seconds intervals.

```
from tkinter import StringVar, Tk, Frame, Label, LabelFrame, mainloop
from platform import system
from random import randint

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        # self.geometry('100x150')
        self.build_ui()
        
    def build_ui(self):
        mainFrame = Frame(self)
        mainFrame.pack()
         
        status_frame = LabelFrame(mainFrame, text='EP status')
        status_frame.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        self._construct_label_colorise(status_frame)
        self.after(1000,self._update_status(status_frame))
    
    #Note!: The number of LABELs delivered by this function in production changes dynamically, it is an unknown total label quantity at each refresh
    
    def _construct_label_colorise(self,master):
        self.label_list=[]
        for x in range(0,randint(3,5)):
            c = randint(0,1)
            fg = "green" if c == 0 else "red"
            label = StringVar
            label = Label(master, text=f'color+{fg}', foreground= fg)
            label.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
            self.label_list.append (label)
        
    def _update_status(self,master):
        for label in self.label_list:
            label.destroy()
        self.after(1000,self._construct_label_colorise(master))
        pass
        
window = Window()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? You say you have trouble with `after` but in your provided example is no `after` method included.

Comment: @Thingamabobs In the example above, I removed my non-working code. 
I am looking for help on correctly placing this after and correctly linking it to an object or even function. 
If you could make this code auto-update labels every x seconds  - that would be a great help. 
I think, I need at the end to have the function _construct_label_colorise rerun every x seconds, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: ALL, I revised the code in the question. I now have the .after() function.
it works partially, I can see it creates my initial labes, then , in 1 second it renews the labels as expected.
It also deletes old labels, and adds new labesl to UI.

The issue I have remaining, is that UI is actually showing at the end + other is only 1 iteration of the loop

Comment: Please follow along the answer of acw1668.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `self.after(1000, self._update_status(status_frame))` will execute `self._update_status(status_frame)` immediately, not 1000ms later.  Also you don't need `self._update_status()` at all for your case.

```py
...
from random import randint, choice

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        # self.geometry('100x150')
        self.build_ui()

    def build_ui(self):
        mainFrame = Frame(self)
        mainFrame.pack()

        status_frame = LabelFrame(mainFrame, text='EP status')
        status_frame.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

        self.label_list = []  # initialize the list here
        self._construct_label_colorise(status_frame)  # start the after loop

    #Note!: The number of LABELs delivered by this function in production changes dynamically, it is an unknown total label quantity at each refresh

    def _construct_label_colorise(self,master):
        # delete existing labels
        for label in self.label_list:
            label.destroy()
        # clear the list
        self.label_list.clear()
        # create random number of labels with random foreground color
        for x in range(0,randint(3,5)):
            fg = choice(["green", "red"])
            label = Label(master, text=f'color+{fg}', foreground= fg)
            label.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
            self.label_list.append (label)
        # call this function one second later
        self.after(1000, self._construct_label_colorise, master)

...
```

Comment: That is what I was missing, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `after`, it will only use the callback *once*.

If you want to keep repeating an action, you have to re-schedule it with `after` every time.

The `_update_status` method should call (not schedule) `_construct_label_colorise` and then re-schedule itself.

Comment: Thanks, Rolan, I thought I did it in my code. Isn't that how you loop it ?  
Can you please point me to the wrong part of the code and propose one that would work? 
I definitely can't understand how that should look.

Comment: @Klimik See updated answer.